How to Auto Login Power BI HTML Static Application
How to Login automatically the PowerBI embedded using LDAP (active directory) credentials.
Using Power BI JavaScript API. I am using below embed code. (Iframe embedding)
I want to avoid Login button and popup.


url = "https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?reportId=GUID&autoAuth=true&ctid=GUID"

document.write(
    "<iframe class='hero' title='Power BI Dashboard' id='myiframe'  src='"+ url +"' frameborder='0' allowFullScreen='true'></iframe>"
  )
  




